# What is the "continue" keyword and how does it work in Java?

Tags: java, keyword, continue

I saw this keyword for the first time and I was wondering if someone could explain to me what it does.

- What is the `continue` keyword?
- How does it work?
- When is it used?

Answer (score 424, accepted):

A `continue` statement without a label will re-execute from the condition the innermost `while` or `do` loop, and from the update expression of the innermost `for` loop.   It is often used to early-terminate a loop's processing and thereby avoid deeply-nested `if` statements.  In the following example `continue` will get the next line, without processing the following statement in the loop.

```
while (getNext(line)) {
  if (line.isEmpty() || line.isComment())
    continue;
  // More code here
}
```

With a label, `continue` will re-execute from the loop with the corresponding label, rather than the innermost loop.  This can be used to escape deeply-nested loops, or simply for clarity.

Sometimes `continue` is also used as a placeholder in order to make an empty loop body more clear.

```
for (count = 0; foo.moreData(); count++)
  continue;
```

The same statement without a label also exists in C and C++.  The equivalent in Perl is `next`.

This type of control flow is not recommended, but if you so choose you can also use `continue` to simulate a limited form of `goto`.  In the following example the `continue` will re-execute the empty `for (;;)` loop.

```
aLoopName: for (;;) {
  // ...
  while (someCondition)
  // ...
    if (otherCondition)
      continue aLoopName;
```

Comment: I would add the caveat that if you have to use a continue keyword, then your loop is busted at a fundamental level and you will be using more memory than you need to and your loop logic is now busted.

Answer (score 529):

`continue` is kind of like `goto`. Are you familiar with `break`? It's easier to think about them in contrast:

- `break` terminates the loop (jumps to the code below it).
- `continue` terminates the rest of the processing of the code within the loop for the current iteration, but continues the loop.

Answer (score 104):

Let's see an example:

```java
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 1; i <= 100 ; i++){
    if(i % 2 == 0)
         continue;
    sum += i;
}
```

This would get the sum of only odd numbers from 1 to 100.

Answer (score 28):

If you think of the body of a loop as a subroutine, `continue` is sort of like `return`. The same keyword exists in C, and serves the same purpose. Here's a contrived example:

```
for(int i=0; i < 10; ++i) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    continue;
  }
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

This will print out only the odd numbers.

Answer (score 16):

Generally, I see `continue` (and `break`) as a warning that the code *might* use some refactoring, especially if the `while` or `for` loop declaration isn't immediately in sight. The same is true for `return` in the middle of a method, but for a slightly different reason.

As others have already said, `continue` moves along to the next iteration of the loop, while `break` moves out of the enclosing loop.

These can be maintenance timebombs because there is no immediate link between the `continue`/`break` and the loop it is continuing/breaking other than context; add an inner loop or move the "guts" of the loop into a separate method and you have a hidden effect of the `continue`/`break` failing.

IMHO, it's best to use them as a measure of last resort, and then to make sure their use is grouped together tightly at the start or end of the loop so that the next developer can  see the "bounds" of the loop in one screen.

`continue`, `break`, and `return` (other than the One True Return at the end of your method) all fall into the general category of "hidden GOTOs". They place loop and function control in unexpected places, which then eventually causes bugs.

Comment: I am interested in the reason why return is bad. I already have a feeling that return is bad because [Scala does not encourage returns](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3770989/243233).

Comment: On the other hand, allowing a method to return from a deeply nested loop might be the easiest, most readable, and most *reasonable* way to do things, rather than creating extra variables just to make the loop exit look more clean.

Answer (score 5):

"continue" in Java means go to end of the current loop,
means: if the compiler sees continue in a loop it will go to the next iteration

Example: This is a code to print the odd numbers from 1 to 10

the compiler will ignore the print code whenever it sees continue moving into the next iteration

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
    if (i%2 == 0) continue;    
    System.out.println(i+"");
}
```

---

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned `continue` will skip processing the code below it and until the end of the loop. Then, you are moved to the **loop's condition** and run the next iteration if this condition still holds (or if there is a flag, to the denoted loop's condition).

It must be highlighted that in the case of `do - while` you are moved to the condition at the bottom after a `continue`, not at the beginning of the loop.

This is why a lot of people fail to correctly answer what the following code will generate.

```
    Random r = new Random();
    Set<Integer> aSet= new HashSet<Integer>();
    int anInt;
    do {
        anInt = r.nextInt(10);
        if (anInt % 2 == 0)
            continue;
        System.out.println(anInt);
    } while (aSet.add(anInt));
    System.out.println(aSet);
```

*If your answer is that `aSet` will contain odd numbers only 100%... you are wrong!

Answer (score 4):

**Continue** is a *keyword* in Java & it is used to skip the current iteration.

Suppose you want to print all odd numbers from 1 to 100

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    //Program to print all odd numbers from 1 to 100

        for(int i=1 ; i<=100 ; i++) {
            if(i % 2 == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(i);
        }

    }
}
```

**continue** statement in the above program simply skips the iteration when **i** is even and prints the value of **i** when it is odd.

**Continue** statement simply takes you out of the loop without executing the remaining statements inside the loop and triggers the next iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Consider an If Else condition. A continue statement executes what is there in a condition and gets out of the condition i.e. jumps to next iteration or condition. But a Break leaves the loop. 
Consider the following Program. '

```
public class ContinueBreak {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] table={"aa","bb","cc","dd"};
        for(String ss:table){
            if("bb".equals(ss)){
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(ss);
            if("cc".equals(ss)){
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Out of the loop.");
    }

}
```

It will print: aa cc Out of the loop.

If you use break in place of continue(After if.), it will just *print aa and out of the loop*.

If the condition "bb" equals ss is satisfied: 
For Continue: It goes to next iteration i.e. "cc".equals(ss).
For Break: It comes out of the loop and prints "Out of the loop. "

Comment: Pretty sure it would also print cc since "cc" != "bb" and the print statement is before the `break`

Answer (score 3):

The continue statement is used in loop control structure when you need to jump to the next iteration of the loop immediately.

It can be used with for loop or while loop. 
The Java continue statement is used to continue the loop. It continues the current flow of the program and skips the remaining code at the specified condition.

In case of an inner loop, it continues the inner loop only.

We can use Java continue statement in all types of loops such as for loop, while loop and do-while loop.

for example

```
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Start");
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            if(i==5){continue;}
            System.out.println("i : "+i);   
        }
        System.out.println("End.");
    }
}
```

output:

```
Start
i : 0
i : 1
i : 2
i : 3
i : 4
i : 6
i : 7
i : 8
i : 9
End.
```

[number 5 is skip]

Answer (score 2):

*I'm a bit late to the party, but...*

It's worth mentioning that `continue` is useful for empty loops where all of the work is done in the conditional expression controlling the loop. For example:

```
while ((buffer[i++] = readChar()) >= 0)
    continue;
```

In this case, all of the work of reading a character and appending it to `buffer` is done in the expression controlling the `while` loop. The `continue` statement serves as a visual indicator that the loop does not need a body.

It's a little more obvious than the equivalent:

```
while (...)
{ }
```

and definitely better (and safer) coding style than using an empty statement like:

```
while (...)
    ;
```

Comment: I definitely agree that it's cleaner and more readable code, but I'm not sure that I follow your argument about it being "safer" than the other option, while(statement);
delimited directly using a semicolon.

Comment: @Aalok - It is safer because a lone semicolon is easy to miss visually. It's also easy to leave out accidentally, which would make the next statement following the `while` become the body of the `while` clause, and which would not be visually obvious. An explicit `continue` is obvious and conveys an intent that an empty statement does not.

Comment: I see, so you mean mainly from a design perspective. That makes sense. I had something underlying with the way the loop is structured in mind.

Answer (score 0):

`continue` must be inside a loop Otherwise it showsThe error below:

> Continue outside the loop