# How to go to next iteration

Tags: java, for-loop, try-catch

Here is what I want to do: In the loop, if the program finds an error, it will print out "Nothing" and go to the next loop (skips print out ""Service discovered at port: " + px + "\n"

```
   for(int px=PORT1; px <=PORT2; px++) { //search
       try{

           Socket s = new Socket(IPaddress,px);
       } catch(Exception e) {
               System.out.print("Nothing\n");
               // I want to go to next iteration

           }
       System.out.print("Service discovered at port: " + px + "\n");
   }
```

What code should I put in the catch? "break" or "next" or ??? 
(This is java)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to only print out a message (or execute some code) if an exception isn't thrown at a particular point, then put that code after the line that might throw the exception:

```
try {
    Socket s = new Socket(IPaddress,px);
    System.out.print("Service discovered at port: " + px + "\n");
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.print("Nothing\n");
}
```

This causes the `print` not to execute if an exception is thrown, since the `try` statement will be aborted.

Alternatively, you can have a `continue` statement from inside the `catch`:

```
try {
    Socket s = new Socket(IPaddress,px);
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.print("Nothing\n");
    continue;
}
System.out.print("Service discovered at port: " + px + "\n");
```

This causes all of the code after the try/catch not to execute if an exception is thrown, since the loop is explicitly told to go to the next iteration.

Comment: +1 for answering the original question and providing a good alternative.

Answer (score 15):

Use the continue keyword:

```
continue;
```

It'll break the current iteration and continue from the top of the loop.

Here's some further reading:

[continue Keyword in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389741/continue-keyword-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

The keyword you're looking for is `continue`. By putting `continue` after your print statement in the `catch` block, the remaining lines after the end of the `catch` block will be skipped the next iteration will begin.

Answer (score 1):

Either

- Use the `continue` keyword in the exception block
- Move the "Service..." to the end of the try block