# Skip to next iteration in loop vba

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to create a simple conditional loop that will go to the next iteration if a condition is true. The code I have so far is:

```
For i = 2 To 24
    Level = Cells(i, 4)
    Return = Cells(i, 5)

    If Return = 0 And Level = 0 Then
        'Go to the next iteration
    Else
    End If
Next
```

I have tried `GoTo NextIteration`, but this comes up with the error 'Label not defined'. This probably has a very simple solution, but assistance would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: whats Level whats Return, what does your spreadsheet look like

Comment: Invert the clause and drop throught? - or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895908/continue-for-loop

Comment: There is no `Continue` in VbScript. You would have to play around `If-Else` to skip any iteration. Go thru the link posted by @AlexK. It has some good suggestions.

Comment: Both Integers, I am trying to make sure that the code doesnt run if both these values are 0.

Comment: Nobody ever said anything about `Return` shouldn't be used... (you know... it is used for other stuff and may lead to huge problems if used as a variable)

Comment: I found `Select Case` useful as well

Answer (score 66):

```
For i = 2 To 24
  Level = Cells(i, 4)
  Return = Cells(i, 5)

  If Return = 0 And Level = 0 Then
    'Go to the next iteration
    GoTo NextIteration
  Else
  End If
  ' This is how you make a line label in VBA - Do not use keyword or
  ' integer and end it in colon
  NextIteration:
Next
```

Comment: Why the `else` after the `if`? I get `end if without if block`.

Comment: It was in the OP's posted code.

Comment: I see, IT life is not copy and paste.

Comment: @timo: It might not have worked like I originally had it so I moved the actual executed 'GoTo' under the comment the way that most people would be accustomed to looking at it.

Answer (score 17):

Just do nothing once the criteria is met, otherwise do the processing you require and the `For` loop will go to the next item.

```
For i = 2 To 24
    Level = Cells(i, 4)
    Return = Cells(i, 5)

    If Return = 0 And Level = 0 Then
        'Do nothing
    Else
        'Do something
    End If
Next i
```

Or change the clause so it only processes if the conditions are met:

```
For i = 2 To 24
    Level = Cells(i, 4)
    Return = Cells(i, 5)

    If Return <> 0 Or Level <> 0 Then
        'Do something
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: shouldn't it be If Return <> 0 Or Level <> 0 Then, so it's the opposite to If Return = 0 And Level = 0 Then?

Comment: The second one seems to work, but I think I need an Or instead of an And. There needs to be an Else too I think.

Answer (score 7):

I use Goto

```
  For x= 1 to 20

       If something then goto continue

       skip this code

  Continue:

  Next x
```

Comment: The simplest (= best) solution (I upvoted), but "skip this code" should read "skip this code if 'something' is true".

Answer (score 5):

The present solution produces the same flow as your OP.
It does not use Labels, but this was not a requirement of the OP. You only asked for "a simple conditional loop that will go to the next iteration if a condition is true", and since this is cleaner to read, **it is likely a better option than that using a Label**.

What you want inside your `for` loop follows the pattern

```
If (your condition) Then
    'Do something
End If
```

In this case, your condition is `Not(Return = 0 And Level = 0)`, so you would use

```
For i = 2 To 24
    Level = Cells(i, 4)
    Return = Cells(i, 5)

    If (Not(Return = 0 And Level = 0)) Then
        'Do something
    End If
Next i
```

PS: the condition is equivalent to `(Return <> 0 Or Level <> 0)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a kind of `continue` by using a nested `Do ... Loop While False`:

```
'This sample will output 1 and 3 only

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 3: Do

    If i = 2 Then Exit Do 'Exit Do is the Continue

    Debug.Print i

Loop While False: Next i
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but not scalable as you then can't have another "do" within the for loop that you can exit from. I guess that's true of all the loop exit options, you can only exit from one of them. You can't loop out from a for-within-a-for to the start of the outer one.