# Excel VBA: Jump inside a for loop: "Next without For" – What am I doing wrong?

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, goto

I honestly do not know why the VBA compiler is nagging me because of that `GoTo Jump`, respectively `Jump:`.

```
    counter2 = 0
    If (counter1 > 1) Then
        For i = 0 To (MaxLastCell - 4)
            If (IncompleteRows(i) = 1) Then
                If ((counter2 > 1) And (counter2 < counter1)) Then
                    x = x + ", " + CLng(i)
                    counter2 = counter2 + 1
                    GoTo Jump
                End If
                If ((counter2 > 1) And (counter2 = counter1)) Then
                    x = x + " and " + CLng(i)
                    GoTo Outside
                If (counter2 = 0) Then
                    x = CLng(i)
                    counter2 = 1
                End If
            End If
Jump:
        Next i
```

Every time I am trying to run my code, this code snippet appears to be a problem. The compiler marks `Next` at the very bottom and tells me that there is a `"Next without For"`.

But shouldn’t this kind of coding work? I just saw it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30448991/7127333). A strange thing, however, is that the compiler there did not seem to coerce [B H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1539001/b-h) to move his jumping point `NextIteration:` to the very left but allowed it to stay at the second indent level and, thus, *within* the `for`-loop, as it seems. (Does that even matter?)

Comment: Change your IF structure to an ElseIF like the answer below. You can then remove the goto Jump line and replace the goto Outside with `Exit For`.

Answer (score 2):

try this (revision marked in comments):

```
    counter2 = 0
    If (counter1 > 1) Then
        For i = 0 To (MaxLastCell - 4)
            If (IncompleteRows(i) = 1) Then
                If ((counter2 > 1) And (counter2 < counter1)) Then
                    x = x + ", " + CLng(i)
                    counter2 = counter2 + 1
                    GoTo Jump
                End If
                If ((counter2 > 1) And (counter2 = counter1)) Then
                    x = x + " and " + CLng(i)
                    GoTo Outside
                ElseIf (counter2 = 0) Then '<--*** changed from simple 'If'
                    x = CLng(i)
                    counter2 = 1
                End If
            End If
Jump:
        Next i
    End If '<--*** added
```

but you should avoid GoTos

Answer (score 2):

You've got some nice spaghetti code there. `GoTo` is but a poor alternative to proper control flow.

[image: Neal Stephenson thinks it's cute to name his labels 'dengo']

One `GoTo` to "skip to next iteration" is one thing. Another to `GoTo Outside` (wherever that is) is something else.

VBA (the language spec) doesn't care on which column a line label starts; for all we know the answer you linked to was typed in the answer box, not in the VBE. When the VBE (the IDE/editor) sees a line label, it moves it to column 1 automatically, just like it automatically inserts spaces between operators and operands, and just like it automatically adjusts the casing of keywords and identifiers as you type them. So no, it doesn't matter at all.

VBA syntax requires blocks to be closed: just like a `Sub DoSomething()` procedure **must** end with `End Sub` and a `With` block **must** end with `End With`, a `For` block **must** end with `Next`. Proper indentation and small procedure bodies usually help getting this right.

A lot of other languages (C#, Java, C++, etc.) have similar constraints about what makes a valid code block (mismatched `{` and `}` braces are a compiler error in every language that uses them AFAIK), so this isn't VBA being picky or complaining for no reason.

That said it's hard to tell whether and where your code is malformed, because you're not including the entire procedure scope so we have to assume there's nothing else that follows your snippet - and the snippet you've posted is missing an `End If` [as user3598756 has noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40492780/1188513):

```
If (counter1 > 1) Then
    '...code...
End If
```

So, how to go about restructuring this?

- Assuming the `Outside` line label is located just before `End Sub` (or is it `End Function`?), then you can replace it with `Exit Sub` (or `Exit Function`) and call it a day.

  - If there's more code that needs to run after the loop but before the end of the procedure scope, `Exit For` will get you out of the loop while keeping you inside the procedure - next line to run will be the first executable statement that follows the `Next` token.
- Now take the condition that makes the loop skip an iteration, and rephrase the loop body accordingly; use `ElseIf` to avoid evaluating conditions you don't need to, and remove all these extraneous and confusing parentheses:

  ```
  If IncompleteRows(i) = 1 And counter2 > 1 And counter2 < counter1 Then
      x = x + ", " + CLng(i)
      counter2 = counter2 + 1
  ElseIf counter2 > 1 And counter2 = counter1 Then
      x = x + " and " + CLng(i)
      Exit For ' assuming...
  ElseIf counter2 = 0 Then
      x = CLng(i)
      counter2 = 1
  End If
  ```

  And that would be the entire body of the loop. Of course it could still be improved; `counter2 > 1` is repeated twice, so there's room for some further restructuring. But already, all `GoTo`'s are gone.