# How to go to next iteration on error AKA simulating Python's "continue" statement in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

In the following code, how do I make the loop continue on next iteraration - not next line - after the error is encountered?

Right now the code will not go past x=0:

```
Sub skip_iteration()

Dim x As Long

For x = 5 To -5 Step -1
    On Error GoTo errhandler:
    Debug.Print 15 / x
    Debug.Print "I don't want this to be printed on error"
Next x

errhandler:
If Err.Number = 11 Then
    Debug.Print ("Error on " & x)
End If

End Sub
```

I have looked into this answer: 
[Skip to next iteration in loop vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681306/skip-to-next-iteration-in-loop-vba/30448991) among others, but could not translate it to my code.

Comment: I thing you want Resume

Comment: @QHarr - `Resume` would result in endless loop. The `Resume Next` in the error handler is the correct way to deal with it.

Comment: @Vityata Correct. I meant it in the error handler. Is there a difference between Resume and Resume Next in this case? Pardon my ignorance. + for your soln.

Comment: @QHarr - I know (for the error handler). The `Resume` there would cause the endless loop.

Comment: My bad! Lesson learnt.

Comment: @QHarr - actually, these two `Resume Next` and `Resume` from the Error handler are really a useful feature. I have updated with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other option here is to inline your error handler. This makes it obvious that you are aware of the potential for a specific line of code to raise an error, and doesn't rely on `Resume` for flow control.  Letting the error go to your handler at the bottom of the function and then jump back into the main line of the code makes it much less obvious what the expected behavior of the loop is.

```
Sub SkipIteration()
    Dim x As Long

    For x = 5 To -5 Step -1
        On Error Resume Next
        Debug.Print 15 / x
        If Err.Number = 11 Then
            Debug.Print "Expected error on " & x
            On Error GoTo errhandler
        Else
            On Error GoTo errhandler
            Debug.Print "Process the rest of the loop"
        End If
    Next x

    Exit Sub
errhandler:
    Debug.Print "Unexpected error "; Err.Number
End Sub
```

Even better would be to separate the concerns of your procedures in a way that the portion of the loop that gets executed is a single statement:

```
Sub SkipIteration()
    On Error GoTo errhandler

    Dim x As Long
    For x = 5 To -5 Step -1
        If TheThingThatCanError(x) Then
            ActionThatDependsOnAbove x
        End If
    Next x

    Exit Sub
errhandler:
    Debug.Print "Unexpected error "; Err.Number
End Sub

Private Function TheThingThatCanError(x As Long) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print 15 / x
    If Err.Number = 11 Then
        Debug.Print "Expected error on " & x
        Exit Function
    End If
    TheThingThatCanError = True
End Function

Private Sub ActionThatDependsOnAbove(x As Long)
    Debug.Print "I don't want this to be printed on error " & x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `Resume Next` to go to the next line after the line, causing the error. And `Err.Clear` is a good practice as well.

The `Exit Sub` before the `errhandler` is also a good practice:

```
Sub SkipIteration()

    Dim x As Long        
    For x = 5 To -5 Step -1
        On Error GoTo errhandler:
        Debug.Print 15 / x
        Debug.Print "testing"
    Next x        
    Exit Sub

errhandler:
    If Err.Number = 11 Then
        Debug.Print ("Error on " & x)
        Err.Clear
        Resume Next
    End If    
End Sub
```

The difference between `Resume` and `Resume Next` is the following:

- `Resume` tries to go back to where it was called.

In the `TestMeResume` procedure, it throws Error 11 at the Debug.Print a/b and in the error handler it assigns b = 5. Then with `Resume` it retries the `Debug.Print a / b`, and as far as `b` is not `0`, it runs.

- `Resume Next` goes to where it was called, ignores the line and continues with the next one.

In the `TestMeResumeNext` procedure, error 91 is thrown at `a = 12` and the error handler is triggered. In the error handler a is assigned to `Range("A14")` and with `Resume Next` the `a = 12` is skipped and the `Sub` continues.

---

```
Sub TestMeResumeNext()

    On Error GoTo TestMeResumeNext_Error

    Dim a As Range
    a = 12              'Error 91 here!
    Debug.Print a.Row   'Resume Next goes back here
    Exit Sub

TestMeResumeNext_Error:
    Set a = Range("A14")
    Resume Next
End Sub

Sub TestMeResume()

    On Error GoTo TestMeResume_Error

    Dim a As Long: a = 10
    Dim b As Long: b = 0
    Debug.Print a / b   'Error 11 here the first time
    Exit Sub

TestMeResume_Error:
    b = 5
    Resume
End Sub
```

Comment: Vityata,many thanks for your thorough answer. However, as I stated in my question, I want to skip to next iteration, not next line. In your code `Resume Next` will go to `Debug.Print "testing"`, and I want to skip it - and whatever might go after it - and go to `Next x` instead.

Comment: @barciewicz - I see. I came up with another answer for this, `GoTo` is somehow bad, dangerous and etc.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to skip the `Error` and continue with the next iteration, a possible way is to use `GoTo` and make some [spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code):

```
Sub SkipIteration()
    Dim x As Long
    For x = 5 To -5 Step -1
        If IsError(Evaluate("15 / " & x)) Then GoTo Skipper
        Debug.Print 15 / x
        Debug.Print x
Skipper:
    Next x
End Sub
```

Or use embed the whole `IsError` check in a if and avoid the `GoTo`. But then you have to go one tab to the right and lose indentation:

```
Sub SkipIteration()
    Dim x As Long
    For x = 5 To -5 Step -1
        If Not IsError(Evaluate("15 / " & x)) Then
            Debug.Print 15 / x
            Debug.Print x
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Using `Evaluate` like that is horrible. Not only does it evaluate the expression twice (once for the `Evaluate` call and once for the "real" call), it offloads it to Excel, which may or may not use the same semantics for a more complicated expression.

Comment: @Comintern - yup, not the best one, but currently cannot come up with a 1-line option. And I do not want to have a dedicated function or `On Error Resume Next`,  because it would be like your answer. :D