# Loop Error (Next without For)

Tags: vba, excel

I am a real VBA amature and would really appreciate some help. 

I have written the below code to cycle through a column, look for a certain string (heading), if the string is found, search for numbers below the string and copy values to a list.  
I am getting a 'Next without For' compile error.
 

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
Sub data()


For i = 0 To 1000

If Range("C1").Offset(i, 0) <> Range("G2") Then Next i Else


For j = 1 To 20

If Not IsNumeric(Range("C1").Offset(i, 0).Offset(j, 0)) Then Next j Else

Range("G1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = Range("C1").Offset(i, 0).Offset(j, 0).Value

Next j
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895908/continue-for-loop

Comment: [Also Checkout loop examples](http://www.xlorate.com/excel-vba-loops.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can change your code as follows:

```
    For i = 0 To 1000
        If Range("C1").Offset(i, 0) = Range("G2") Then
            For j = 1 To 20
                If IsNumeric(Range("C1").Offset(i, 0).Offset(j, 0)) Then
                   Range("G1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = Range("C1").Offset(i, 0).Offset(j, 0).Value
                EndIf
            Next j
        EndIf
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This just looks awful. Let me help.

Firs, try to use the `If` like this:

```
If *condition* then
    'what you want to do
else
    'in every other cases, what do you want to do
End if
```

And use `For` like:

```
For i = 1 To *number of times you want to loop*
    'what do you want to loop
Next i
```

If you put `If` inside `For`, You close the `If` first; if you put `For` inside `If`, you always use `Next i` before `End if`

for example:

```
For i = 1 To *number of times you want to loop*
    If *condition* then
        'what you want to do
    else
        'if the condition is not true, what do you want to do
    End if
Next i
```