# Exit nested 'If' statement

Tags: excel, vba

I want the code below to do evaluate each line in a dataset, match column 35 to a range and then paste in the correct tab.

I'm having trouble with the `If Not IsError` statement. In an instance where the match doesn't occur, I want the `If Not Then` to skip the remaining nested code and jump to the end of the `For` Loop, moving to the next row `iRow`.

```
Sub testFind()    
    Dim csCount As Range
    Dim b As Variant
    Dim shrow As Long
    Dim iRow As Long, iRowL As Long, var As Variant
    Dim bln As Boolean
    Dim s As String
    Dim eRow As Integer

    Set csCount = Worksheets("Input").Range("csCount")   
    iRowL = Cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For iRow = 2 To iRowL  
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(iRow, 35)) Then
            bln = False
            var = Application.Match(Cells(iRow, 35).Value, Worksheets("Input").Columns(3), 0)
            If Not IsError(var) Then
                Sheets("GL008").rows(iRow).copy
                s = Sheets("GL008").Cells(iRow, 35)
                Sheets(s).Activate
                eRow = Sheets(s).Cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Sheets(s).rows(eRow)
            End If
        End If   
    Next iRow   
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not trying to exit the For, I'm trying to exit the If and continue to the next iRow within the For.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895908/continue-for-loop

Answer (score 1):

Use `CvErr`

Instead of

```
If Not IsError(Var) Then
    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
End If
```

use this

```
If Not CVErr(Var) = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
End If
```

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: Sure thing, where can I do this?