# What will this continue cause the nested for-loop to do?

Tags: java, for-loop, continue

I've searched SO and can find questions addressing similar subjects, but nothing for this specific question and language. After reading some Q&A and not finding the answer, I searched [java](/questions/tagged/java), [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) and [continue](/questions/tagged/continue) and got zero results.

I've been asked this question in a university quiz:

If I have:

```
int n = 3;
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)  {
      System.out.print(" x ");
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)  {
         System.out.println(" x ");
           continue;
           //no content here
        }
     }
```

Without there being any content after the continue statement; how does this  using `continue` affect this loop? Does it cause a break in the second loop of does the loop continue to iterate?

Comment: There is no sense of putting a `continue` like that. Removing it will give you same behaviour. Basically, it is used to continue the iteration of current loop, without moving further.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389741/continue-keyword-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there was a code under `continue`, it'll be a *dead code* (unreachable code).

The way you wrote it, it has no effect since it's already the last line. The loop would have continued if there was no `continue;`.

These two blocks of code have the same effect:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   // .. code ..
}
```

---

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   // .. code ..
   continue;
}
```

However, the below snippet has unreachable code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   // .. code ..
   continue;
   // .. unreachable code ..
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A `continue` statement without a label will **re-execute from the condition the innermost while or do, or loop, and from the update expression the innermost for loop**. It is often used to early-terminate a loop's processing and thereby avoid deeply-nested if statements.

Hence for your program , the keywork `continue` doesn't make much sense. It is used as a kind of a escape thing. For e.g:

```
aLoopName: for (;;) {
  // ...
  while (someCondition)
  // ...
    if (otherCondition)
      continue aLoopName;
```

Say, if you modify your program like:

```
int n = 3;
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)  {
      System.out.print(" x ");
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)  {
         if(j%2!=0)
         {
          System.out.println(" x ");
          continue;
         }
         else
         break;
     }
```

This will break the **inner** for loop for j=2. Hope you understand. :)

Comment: Your question is seemingly vague. The `continue` keyword placed in the inner for loop has no sense. Even if you remove the keyword it wont make any difference. It's better to understand how and when `continue` is used and not use it randomly anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question:

**How does this using continue affect this loop? Does it cause a break in the second loop of does the loop continue to iterate?**

is:

The second loop will not break, it will continue to iterate. `break` keyword is for breaking loop.

**EDIT**

Suppose you have `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   continue;
}
```

`continue` in for executes the statement of `for` loop (`i++`) to continue to the next iteration.

In other loops, `while{}` or `do{}while();` the things will not be like this and may cause infinite loops.