# Alternative for 'continue' keyword

Tags: java, loops, continue

I was browsing through questions regarding `continue` keyword to get a better understanding of it and I stumbled upon this line [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/390346/1686291)

> These can be maintenance timebombs because there is no immediate link between the "continue"/"break" and the loop it is continuing/breaking other than context;

I have this for loop:

```
for(Object obj : myArrayList){
  if(myArrayList.contains(someParticularData)){
       continue;
    }
   //do something
}
```

Now, my question is - Is it okay to use `continue` in the manner that I have done above or does it have any issues? If yes, what is the alternative approach that I can follow? Any kind of guidance would help. Thank you.

**Update:** My objective in this particular situation would be to iterate over a   `Collection` ( `ArrayList`, in this case), and check if that contains some particular data   and skip that iteration if it is true.
I was pointed out that `myArrayList.contains(someParticularData)` is a one time operation and that it would be better off to perform that check outside the loop, which is what I was looking for. Also, I learnt that if I can use `continue` based on some condition `if(someConditon)`, I can very well avoid it by using `if(!someCondition)`.

Comment: I think it just depends on how you want the loop to work.

Comment: The usage depends on your logical implementation. One box doesn't fit for all sizes.

Comment: Will effect readability and code maintenance if you are nesting loops, otherwise it is ok.

Comment: Don't close question as "primarily opinion-based" if you think Question is not suitable for SO flag to migrate to [Programmers Stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: _slightly related side note_: the use of continue/break could in some respect be equated with the concept of [Single Function Exit Point](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingleFunctionExitPoint) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement

Comment: and a try catch inside the for loop and if the condition does not satisfy throw a custom exception (say) ValidationFailsException and eat that exception. This way it is clear to the consumer of the code the reason for exiting out and as the exception is eaten, the loop can continue

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
for(Object obj : myArrayList){
    if(someCondition){
       continue;
    }
    //do something 
}
```

can be replaced with:

```
for(Object obj : myArrayList){
    if(!someCondition){
       //do something 
    }
}
```

IMHO, as far as you don't have a lot (like 2-3 `continue`/`break`/`return`), maintenance will be fine.

Answer (score 13):

This code is of *little use*

```
  for(Object obj : myArrayList) {
    // You're checking again and agian the condition that's loop independent
    if(myArrayList.contains(someParticularData)){
      continue;
    }
   //do something
  }
```

A *more effective* implementation is (check whether you need the loop *at all* first)

```
  if (!myArrayList.contains(someParticularData))
    for(Object obj: myArrayList) {
      //do something
    }
```

**continue** is convenient in conditions like that:

```
  for(Object obj : myArrayList) {
    // Check for each item: do we need to proceed this item
    if (someArrayList.contains(obj))
      continue;

    //do something
  }
```

Comment: good catch! I missed that

Comment: I'm sorry but were you asking me to check if the `for` loop is needed at all? If so, yes, I need to loop through a `Collection` and in case it contains a particular data, I want to skip that iteration.

Comment: @AnjanBaradwaj - What Dmitry is trying to say is "ArrayList.contains()" is a one-time operation.. putting it in a for loop doesn't help..

Comment: @Dmitry , I assume that `Contains` in the last snippet was supposed to be lower case?

Comment: @Dennis Meng: Yes, thank you! I haven't switched my mind from C# (where "Contains" capitalized) to Java

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are looping on some value range, you are processing on each of the value comes between the initial and final one...

For example if you are making addition of odd numbers.
it is convenient to use loop which will be incremented by 2 rather than continuing for each odd value,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100 ; i=i+2){
   // do addition
}
```

but if you are modifying your value that is being checked within the loop, than `continue` or `break` is good practice to implement.

for example,

```
boolean flag = false;
// flag will be modified in some iteration of loop, but you don't know which.
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++ ) {
   if ( flag ) {
      continue;
   }
   // flag modified somewhere..
}
```