# How does continue work?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, break, continue

I am trying to understand how "continue" works. I understood the concept of the keyword but when I run different programs, it works differently :-/
Let me show you few examples:

If I run this program :

```
int j = 0;
int i = 0;
LABEL1: for (; i < 3; i++) {
  if (true)
    continue;
}
```

The value of i is gonna be 3. so far so good.
Let's add an outer loop :

```
int j = 0;
int i = 0;
LABEL2: for (; j < 3; j++) {
  LABEL1: for (; i < 3; i++) {
    if (true)
      continue LABEL2;
  }
}
```

The value of i is gonna be ... 0 !! 
I don't understand why i is not incremented if continue is used with a label that goes to the outer loop. Can somebody explain it why ? 
Do you have some tricky things like that with break ? or with a do {} while ?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: i is never incremented  bc you continue the outter loop

Comment: continue with label will go the the position the label indicates. Here continue jumps to LABEL2, so i++ is not executed.

Comment: Thanks guys! I understood. You helped me a lot!
I just found something that may help somebody else to understand how continue works with a loop for : 
 continue causes the control flow to jump to the loop condition (for while, do while loops) or to the update (for for loops). This causes control flow to jump to the next iteration.                
Hey, is it possible to tag it as solved ?

Comment: @user3884432 in order to "mark it as solved" just accept the answer you like most from the below. There are plenty of good ones. If you don't like them, write your own answer and accept that.

Comment: Effectively, `continue` branches you to the end of the loop, just before the closing `}`.  This results in the loop condition being re-evaluated, just as would occur had your program flow "fallen through" to the bottom of the loop.  In the case of `continue label;`, control transfers to the bottom of the loop identified by `label:`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The basic `for` statement structure is as follows:

```
BasicForStatement:
for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) Statement
```

Now, from [**JLS §14.14.1.3.  Abrupt Completion of `for` Statement**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1.3):

> If execution of the *Statement* completes abruptly because of a **`continue` with no label**, then the following two steps are performed in sequence:
>
> 1. First, **if the *ForUpdate* part is present, the expressions are evaluated** in sequence from left to right; their values, if any, are discarded. If the *ForUpdate* part is not present, no action is taken.
> 2. Second, another `for` iteration step is performed.
>
> If execution of the *Statement* completes abruptly because of a **`continue` with label `L`**, then there is a choice:
>
> - If the `for` statement has label `L`, then the following two steps are performed in sequence:
>
>   1. First, if the *ForUpdate* part is present, the expressions are evaluated in sequence from left to right; their values, if any, are discarded. If the *ForUpdate* is not present, no action is taken.
>   2. Second, another `for` iteration step is performed.
> - **If the `for` statement does not have label `L`, the `for` statement completes abruptly because of a continue with label `L`.**

(emphasis mine)

*ForUpdate*, in your case, is `i++`. Based on what's above:

- Your first snippet falls under the first case, so `i` is incremented.
- Your second snippet falls under the second case, so `i` is not incremented because the  `for` statement completes abruptly.

Note that if you had `continue LABEL1` in your second snippet, `i` would have been incremented as in your first snippet (in accordance with the JLS).

As a tip for the future, for *definitive* answers regarding language rules/semantics, you should *always* consult the language specification. For Java, that's the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/).

Comment: One might also note that 14.14.1.2 specifies that evaluation of [Expression] is part of the iteration step.  Otherwise a naive reading of the spec could indicate that neither snippet should terminate.

Answer (score 14):

This is really normal. The exectuion flow is like this:

1. j=0
2. i=0
3. LABEL 2 loop entered,
4. LABEL 1 loop entered,
5. continue to LABEL 2
6. j++
7. LABEL 1 loop entered,
8. continue to LABEL 2
9. j++
10. LABEL 1 loop entered,
11. continue to LABEL 2
    ... until j==3

Comment: It would help to show what's different in the first snippet.

Comment: This does not deserve upvotes. It does not explain what continue does. Showing the flow of exexution is not an answer

Comment: @VinceEmigh It's useful and too long to format nicely in a comment. Might make a good meta topic if you don't think it qualifies as an answer.

Comment: For a top class answer, a flow chart would greatly improve the readability of this answer.  As it is, it is rather crowded.

Comment: in fact, what I wanted to show is that the question here is not how continue works, but how for works.

Answer (score 7):

`i` would be increased at the end of the inner loop. But `continue LABEL2` jumps out of the inner loop, to the end of the outer loop, so `i` is not increased; instead only `j` is increased until the outer loop condition is no longer met.

Maybe it becomes clearer when we rewrite the code with `while` loops instead:

```
int j=0;
int i = 0;
while (j<3) {
    while(i<3) {
       if (true)
           goto END_OF_LOOP2;

       END_OF_LOOP1: i++;
    }
    END_OF_LOOP2: j++;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Continue simply does what its name suggests, it immediately continues to the next execution of the loop without executing the rest of the code in the loop.

So if you have a loop like this:

```
int j=0;
int i = 0;
    LABEL1 : for(;i < 3; i++){
        if (true) {
            continue;
        }
        someOtherMethod();
    }
```

The someOtherMethod part is never executed because you will always hit the continue.

The reason your counter is never incremented has to do with labels, you can mark a loop with a label (in your case `LABEL1` and `LABEL2` and use that label to continue one of the outer loops of your inner loop.

So with your code the loop of `LABEL1` never gets a chance to increment its counter and thus `i` remains `0` because your continue statement immediately continues to the next iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 4):

```
continue LABEL2;
```

causes that only the outter loop increasing. if you have

```
LABEL2 : for(;j <3;j++){
    LABEL1 : for(;i < 3; i++){
             if (true)
                 continue LABEL1;
             }
     }
```

`i` will increase.

Answer (score 3):

If this is the code,
for example:

```
    int main (){
      // Local variable declaration:

    int a = 10;

   // do loop execution
  do
  {
     if( a == 15)
     {
        // skip the iteration.
        a = a + 1;
        continue;
      }
      cout << "value of a: " << a << endl;
           a = a + 1;
         }while( a < 20 );
         return 0;
     }
```

Then the result will be

```
value of a: 10
value of a: 11
value of a: 12
value of a: 13
value of a: 14
value of a: 16
value of a: 17
value of a: 18
value of a: 19
```

POINT TO BE NOTED:
"value of a: 15" is not in the output.
continue in programming language skips that certain line in a loop, if "break" used, then break just gets off that line after "14" (in this case).
For your understanding, please see the following flowchart:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> **`i`** is incremented when next time condition is checked.

If you `continue` or `break` the loop then condition will not be checked again and will never increment the value of `i`.

for

```
LABEL1 : for(;i < 3; i++){
               if (true)
                   continue;
             }
```

when you continue you're again checking if value of `i` is less then 3 at that moment before checking that condition compiler internally increments the value of `i`.

Here

```
LABEL2 : for(;j <3;j++){
        LABEL1 : for(;i < 3; i++){
                 if (true)
                     continue LABEL2;
                 }
         }
```

When you're executing `continue` condition for `Label1` is never checked again, and will directly go to the statement with `Label2` so it will never get incremented.

Same is with the break

```
LABEL1 : for(;i < 3; i++){
               if (true)
                   break;
             }
```

if you execute the above code value of `i` will be `0` and not `1`.

Answer (score 2):

If you run this in debug mode, you will see what happens. In short, whenever you enter the inner loop to increment the `i`, you will instead `continue` to `LABEL2` instead of incrementing `i` and going to the next iteration of the inner loop.

Thus, you will be in the outer loop 3 times and you will never hit the `i++` in the inner loop.

If it's easier, think of the inner for loop like a while loop:

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
LABEL2: for (; j < 3; j++) {
  LABEL1: while (i < 3) {
    if (true) {
      continue LABEL2;
    }

    i++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `continue` statement without a label will re-execute from the condition the innermost while or do, or loop, and from the update expression the innermost for loop. It is often used to early-terminate a loop's processing and thereby avoid deeply-nested if statements. In the following example continue will get the next line, without processing the following statement in the loop.

```
while (getNext(line)) {
  if (line.isEmpty() || line.isComment())
    continue;
  // More code here
}
```

With a label continue will execute in the same way the correspondingly labeled loop. This can be used to escape deeply-nested loops, or simply for clarity. If you're truly perverse you can also use it to simulate a limited form of `goto`. In the following example the `continue` will re-execute the `for (;;)` loop.

```
aLoopName: for (;;) {
  // ...
  while (someCondition)
  // ...
    if (otherCondition)
      continue aLoopName;
```

Sometimes `continue` is also used as a placeholder in order to make an empty loop body clearer.

```
for (count = 0; foo.moreData(); count++)   continue;
```

The same statement without a `label` also exists in C and C++. In Perl it's named `next`.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389741/continue-keyword-in-java)