# Can you use conditional statements in switch-case in Android?

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I can't seem to find a straight forward yes or no to this in my searching. In Android, is there a way to use a conditional statement in case-switch? For example, with age being an int value:

```
switch (age){
case (>79):
 // Do this stuff
 break;
case (>50):
 // Do this other stuff
break;
etc, etc
```

I've tried several ways to code this (completely shooting in the dark) and come up with compiler errors, and I've also tried a nested IF statement, but it doesn't support break so the logic breaks down and it ends up also executing ELSE code lower in the nesting. I feel like switch-case is my best bet but I can't find an example of the correct syntax for what I'm trying to do! Any help would be appreciated. All the examples I find just use switch-case for a few things like if it is a 1 do this, if it's a 2 do that, but without making 100 case statements to check against age, I'm not sure how else to work this.

Comment: Are you running this through a loop? Try posting more of your code.

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389741/continue-keyword-in-java. This is not a good place to use switch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. You cannot do this,

```
switch (age){
case (>79):
  // Do this stuff
  break;
case (>50):
  // Do this other stuff
  break;
}
```

You need an `if` and `else`,

```
if (age > 79) {
 // do this stuff.
} else if (age > 50) {
 // do this other stuff.
} // ...
```

Comment: The only problem then is lets say the age is 51, it will do the age 50 if, but also the age 45 if, age 35 if, etc. I tried using "break;" but that, apparently, doesn't work with a nested if. So How do you get it to do just the one without all the lower ones?

Comment: Exactly as I said in my answer, it won't enter the `else` block if the `if` block is entered. This is not a `switch`.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, once an if condition is met it no longer evaluates all the other nested if's in that block of nested ifs? So it's like the break is implied?

Comment: @Robert No. These are not nested ifs. This is `if` and then `else`. `if (a > 5) { AAA; } else if (a > 3) { BBB; } else { CCC; }` if a is 6 would do AAA (and *nothing* else). if a is 4 it would do BBB (and *nothing* else). If a is -1 it would do CCC.... first test, second test, otherwise....

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand it now. I'm probably not using the right words since I'm very new to this and learning, but I get it! :-)

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible. Instead, Try this minimalist approach

```
 age > 79 ? first_case_method() 
          : age > 50 ? second_case_method() 
          : age > 40 ? third_case_method() 
          : age > 30 ? fourth_case_method() 
          : age > 20 ? fifth_case_method()
          : ... 
          : default_case_method();
```

Comment: This does not directly relate to the question, even through it can be seen as a valid answer. Please provide some more details, as the question is about a switch statement and your answer provides an if-then-else solution.

Comment: @hotzst Like already mentioned by the others, there is no way to use conditional statements in the java switch loop. instead, maybe this way to handle the situation could be less wordy.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this use if then statement.

```
if(age > 79)
{
   //do stuff
}
else if(age > 50)
{
   //do stuff
}
else
{
   /do stuff
}
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a loop you might want to look at [What is the "continue" keyword and how does it work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389741/continue-keyword-in-java). This is not a good place to use switch.

```
if(age > 79)
{
   //do stuff
   continue; // STOP FLOW HERE AND CONTINUE THE LOOP
}
else if(age > 50)
{
   //do stuff
   continue; // STOP FLOW HERE AND CONTINUE THE LOOP
}
```

Answer (score 0):

each case of switch is supposed to be an integer or String since JavaSE 7 and you are trying to feed a boolean value to it so its not possible .Read oracle doc to know about java switch in detail
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score -1):

You can't use conditional statements with `switch`.

But you CAN do it with `if` statements! If you have a loop you can use `continue` to stop any upcoming lines and start from the beginning of the innermost loop.

```
if(age>76){
    // Code...
    continue;
}else if(age>50){
    // More Code...
    continue;
}else{
    // Even more code...
    continue;
}
```

Comment: The breaks int he switch that the user who posted this question included make the continue not needed.

Answer (score -5):

It can be done.
The code needs to be slightly altered.

```
public static void main(String[]arguments)
    {
        int x=1, age=55;
        switch(x)
        {
        case 1: if((age>=60)&&(age<200))
            System.out.println("Senior Citizen");
        case 2: if((age>=18)&&(age<60))
            System.out.println("Adult");
        case 3: if((age>=12)&&(age<18))
            System.out.println("Teenager");
            break;
        default :
            System.out.println("Child");
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: That's not going to work. Since `x = 1`, you'll always end up at `case 1`.

Comment: Thats not right. I did not use a break after each case. So it verifies every case and not just case 1.

Comment: I did miss that. But then what is the purpose of the switch-statement? It's effectively just a chain if-statements then.

Comment: This gets my personal award for misuse of switch/case