# Input Validation Java

Tags: java

I am pretty new to Java. I am doing a program that calculates an Income Tax summary based on one's marital status. My program works, aside from one problem: my input validation section for the marital status is not working properly. When I enter something other than s, S, m, M, c, and C, the program is supposed to perform input validation for that, but currently, when I enter something like x, it skips the gross income and exemptions, and spits out that tax rate, taxes owed, and taxable income are all 0.

EDIT: Sorry if that was confusing. Basically, if the user uses invalid input, and the user then enters something valid, I want to know how to make it go back to the beginning of the switch statement to determine the tax rate Any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TaxPrep
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        char maritalStatus;
        double grossIncome = 0;
        double numberOfExemptions = 0;
        double taxRate = 0;
        double taxableIncome = 0;
        double taxesOwed = 0;
        String anotherCustomer = "y";

        System.out.print("_ _ _ _ _ ' S  T A X  P R E P A R E R\n\n");

        do{
            System.out.print("Are you (s)ingle, (m)arried, or (c)ohabiting?\n");
            System.out.print("Enter s, m, or c ==> ");
            maritalStatus = sc.next().charAt(0);
            switch (maritalStatus)
            {
                case 's': case 'S':
                    System.out.print("Gross income ==> ");
                    grossIncome = sc.nextDouble();
                    System.out.print("Number of exemptions ==> ");
                    numberOfExemptions = sc.nextInt();
                    taxableIncome = grossIncome - (1000 * numberOfExemptions);
                    taxRate = 20;
                    break;
                case 'm': case 'M':
                    System.out.print("Gross income ==> ");
                    grossIncome = sc.nextDouble();
                    System.out.print("Number of exemptions ==> ");
                    numberOfExemptions = sc.nextInt();
                    taxableIncome = grossIncome - (1000 * numberOfExemptions);
                    taxRate = 25;
                    break;
                case 'c': case 'C': //tax rate for cohabiting depends on taxable income
                    System.out.print("Gross income ==> ");
                    grossIncome = sc.nextDouble();
                    System.out.print("Number of exemptions ==> ");
                    numberOfExemptions = sc.nextInt();
                    taxableIncome = grossIncome - (1000 * numberOfExemptions);
                    if (taxableIncome <= 20_000)
                    {
                        taxRate = 10;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (taxableIncome <= 50_000)
                    {
                        taxRate = 15;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        taxRate = 30;
                        break;
                    }
                default: //if input for marital status is invalid
                    do{ //continues to ask for valid input until user inputs a valid marital status
                        System.out.print("\nInvalid entry.");
                        System.out.print("\nAre you (s)ingle, (m)arried, or (c)ohabiting?");
                        System.out.print("\nEnter s, m, or c ==> ");
                        maritalStatus = sc.next().charAt(0);
                    } while (maritalStatus != 's' && maritalStatus != 'S' && maritalStatus != 'm' && maritalStatus != 'M' && maritalStatus != 'c' && maritalStatus != 'C');
            } 

            taxesOwed = taxableIncome * (taxRate / 100);

            //taxable income and taxes owed cannot be negative
            if (taxableIncome < 0)
            {
                taxableIncome = 0;
            }
            if (taxesOwed < 0)
            {
                taxesOwed = 0;
            }

            //tax summary
            System.out.print("\nINCOME TAX SUMMARY");
            System.out.print("\ntax rate: " + taxRate + "%");
            System.out.print("\ntaxable income: $" + taxableIncome);
            System.out.print("\ntaxes owed: $" + taxesOwed);

            //would you like to process another customer?
            System.out.print("\n\nProcess another customer? (y/n): ");
            anotherCustomer = sc.next();
            System.out.print("\n");
        } while (anotherCustomer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")); //as long as user enters 'y' or 'Y', the program will continue to calculate the income tax summary
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of retrying after

```
default: //if input for marital status is invalid
   do{ //continues to ask for valid input until user inputs a valid marital status
   } while(...);
```

simply skip to the end of the outer loop:

```
default:
    System.out.print("\nInvalid entry.");
    continue;
```

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thank you! What does continue; do btw?

Comment: @IronMaiden28 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389741/what-is-the-continue-keyword-and-how-does-it-work-in-java

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the switch-Statement inside the do-while-loop you got in default in your example, like

```
boolean martialStatusValid = true
maritalStatus = sc.next().charAt(0);    
do {
    martialStatusValid = true;
    switch (maritalStatus) {
       //your cases here
       default:
           martialStatusValid = false;
           //display some kind of error message ... 
    }
} while (! martialStatusValid)
```

That way, as long as the martialStatus is invalid the User will be prompted for new input and the switch will repeat.

One thing to note abound Launes "continue-solution: that will start the next iteration of the outer do-loop, so basically restart your Program. Might not be what you're after if you have more Sections with user input, f.e. if you want to ask for sex etc.