# Loop with "continue" or back to condition

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, continue

A have an error there. I tried to write a continue in loop and this didn't working(or jump to back). I'm begginer soo please be do not be angry after read this. Please help me!

```
somepoint: { Random first = new Random();
        int b = first.nextInt(8);
        if (b==0)
        {
            x=x+20;
            for (int c=0; c<100; c++)
            {
                if (x>=950)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Winner is white car!");
                    return;
                }
                else 
                {
                    continue somepoint; //cannot be used outside, help
                }
            }
        }
        else if (b==1)
        {
            x2=x2+20;
            for (int c=0; c<100; c++)
            {
                if (x2>=950)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Winner is red car!");
                    return;
                }
                else 
                {
                    continue somepoint; //cannot be used outside,
                }
            }
        }
        else if (b==2) ...
```

Comment: People generally consider it bad practice to jump in the code like this.  Have you tried using other looping structures like a while loop to contain the code?

Comment: @phflack noo, okey I'll try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a really bad practice to jump in the code like this. Have you consider using a recursive method?

If you want to make use of `continue` properly , you should read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389741/what-is-the-continue-keyword-and-how-does-it-work-in-java).