# Adding prime number under a limit

Tags: java, primes

I want to add prime numbers under two million, and for some reason it keeps running with no output. After some testing I know that the error itself is in the the `addprimes` function however from what I understand the program should return an output.

```
static ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static void findPrimes(int limit)
{
    primes.add(2);
    int Number = 3;
    int n = 0;
    boolean add = true;

    if(Number % 2 != 0)
        primes.add(Number);

    for(int i = Number; i<limit; i+=2)
    {
        n = 2;
        add = true;


        while(n < i)
        {
            if(i % n == 0)
            {
                add = false;
                continue;
            }
            n++;
        }


        if(add == true)
            primes.add(i);

    }
}


public static int addPrimes()
{
    int Total = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++)
    {
        temp = primes.get(i);
        Total += temp;
    }
    return Total;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `continue` without increment the value of `n`.

Try updating `while` loop to the following:

```
while(n < i)
{
   if(i % n == 0)
   {
       add = false;
       n++;
       continue;
   }
   else
       n++;
}
```

Check the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389741/what-is-the-continue-keyword-and-how-does-it-work-in-java) for more information about `continue`.

**Update**

In case your code ended up with too big numbers, then you have to use another data-types like Long, Double ..etc.

Comment: Thanks now it works for int, however if the number is too big then like the problem asks, then it does not but I think I know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Good luck, but if you found my answer helpful; you could check it as a Correct Answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can just comment out *continue* to come out of infinite loop.
2. I can see that value 3 is repeating in the prime number list for that you can comment out these lines

   ```
   //    if(Number % 2 != 0) 
   //          primes.add(Number);
   ```