# Continue for loop until string match

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm searching a way to continue a for-loop until a string matches.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public ItemStack[] loadSecoundtLaserInventory(){
    ItemStack pan = new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, 1, DyeColor.BLACK.getWoolData());
    ItemMeta panmeta = pan.getItemMeta();
    panmeta.setDisplayName("");
    pan.setItemMeta(panmeta);
    List<ItemStack> content = new ArrayList<ItemStack>();
    content.add(pan);
    //
    for(String str : getConfig().getConfigurationSection("lasers").getKeys(false)){
        if(!str.startsWith("2")){

        }
        String[] amounts = getConfig().getString("lasers." + str + "amount").split(";");
        ItemStack is1 = new ItemStack(getConfig().getInt("lasers." + str + ".block-id"));
        ItemMeta ismeta1 = is1.getItemMeta();
        ismeta1.setLore(Arrays.asList(HiddenStringUtil.encodeString(str)));
        ismeta1.setDisplayName(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', getConfig().getString("lasers." + str + ".dname-amount").replace("{amount}", amounts[0])));
        ItemStack is2 = new ItemStack(getConfig().getInt("lasers." + str + ".block-id"));
        ItemMeta ismeta2 = is2.getItemMeta();
        ismeta2.setLore(Arrays.asList(HiddenStringUtil.encodeString(str)));
        ismeta2.setDisplayName(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', getConfig().getString("lasers." + str + ".dname-amount").replace("{amount}", amounts[1])));
        ItemStack is3 = new ItemStack(getConfig().getInt("lasers." + str + ".block-id"));
        ItemMeta ismeta3 = is3.getItemMeta();
        ismeta3.setLore(Arrays.asList(HiddenStringUtil.encodeString(str)));
        ismeta3.setDisplayName(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', getConfig().getString("lasers." + str + ".dname-amount").replace("{amount}", amounts[2])));
        is2.setItemMeta(ismeta2);
        if(!content.contains(is1)){
            content.add(is1);
        }
        if(content.size() == 2){
            content.add(pan);
            content.add(pan);
        }
        if(!content.contains(is2)){
            content.add(is2);
        }
        if(content.size() == 5){
            content.add(pan);
            content.add(pan);
        }
        if(!content.contains(is3)){
            content.add(is3);
        }
        if(content.size() == 8){
            content.add(pan);
            return content.stream().toArray(ItemStack[]::new);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Basically the Strings i loop over is something like

```
1panda,2boom,3tnt.
```

The problem is when the string doesn't starts with 2, i want to continue to the next String.
I cannot use the return statement, because it would stop the loop.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for `break;` ?

Comment: @AntonH: I think he wants `continue;`

Comment: I think you can add it as an answer @ThomasWeller

Comment: Or mark it as a duplicate :)

Comment: @ThomasWeller Yes, I was misreading ...

Comment: @Ruben: If `continue;` solves the problem, just delete the question, please.

Comment: Thanks to everyone! It does his job!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `continue;`. [What is the "continue" keyword and how does it work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389741/what-is-the-continue-keyword-and-how-does-it-work-in-java)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
        continue;
    } else {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Will print only the odd numbers. Obviously, that's a bit of a contrived example, since you could have just done the print on `if(i % 2 !=)`, but I hope you get the idea.