# How to skip reading a line with scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have read in a text file and am scanning said file. The question I have is how would I skip over lines that include a certain character (in my case lines that start with " // " and "   " (whitespace).

Here is my code at the moment. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
    File dataFile = new File(filename);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dataFile);


      while(scanner.hasNext())
      {
         String lineOfText = scanner.nextLine();
         if (lineOfText.startsWith("//")) {
           System.out.println(); // not sure what to put here
         }
      System.out.println(lineOfText);
      }
   scanner.close();
```

Comment: How about a simple `continue;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only want to execute the code within the while-loop if the line of text doesn't start with a `/` or whitespace.  You can filter these out as seen below:

```
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
   String lineOfText = scanner.nextLine();
   if (lineOfText.startsWith("//") || lineOfText.startsWith(" ")) {
      continue; //Exit this iteration if line starts with space or /
   }
   System.out.println(lineOfText);
}
```

Comment: I will later have to read the data into the fields of other classes using a second scanner. Will it not read the data with the lines that I wish to be ignored?

Comment: There are no fields being read into in your question.  If you want to do something with the lineOfText, then include it in the if-statement.  Otherwise the line will just be skipped as I assume you require.

Comment: I feel as if I should have worded the question a bit better. My bad. I want to completely ignore the lines with "//" and white space, as I will be using the actual data later for storing in arrays.

Comment: In this case you will want to use continue.  I have edited my answer, and no problem!

Comment: Thanks for the swift answers!

Answer (score 1):

As you are iterating over the lines of text in the file, use `String`'s [`startsWith()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) method to check if the line starts with the sequences you are trying to avoid.

If it does, continue to the next line. Otherwise, print it.

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String lineOfText = scanner.nextLine();

    if (lineOfText.startsWith("//") || lineOfText.startsWith(" ") ) {
        continue;
    }

    System.out.println(lineOfText);
}
```

Comment: please add an explanation for your code - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15465052)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `continue` like  -

```
if (lineOfText.startsWith("//")) {
  continue; //would skip the loop to next iteration from here
}
```

Detials - [What is the "continue" keyword and how does it work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389741/what-is-the-continue-keyword-and-how-does-it-work-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just interested in printing out the lines of code that begin with a "//" then you should just use the continue keyword in java.

```
String lineOfText = scanner.nextLine();
if (lineOfText.startsWith("//")) {
    continue;
}
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389741/what-is-the-continue-keyword-and-how-does-it-work-in-java) for more information regarding the "continue" keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can just insert "else" in your code like:

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

```
     File dataFile = new File("testfile.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dataFile);


          while(scanner.hasNext())
          {
             String lineOfText = scanner.nextLine();
             if (lineOfText.startsWith("//")) {
               System.out.println(); 
             }
             else
                 System.out.println(lineOfText);
          }
       scanner.close();
}
```

}